# NLog with Windsor Castle - how to save log to database (.NET Core 3.1)

Tags: castle-windsor, asp.net-core-3.1, nlog

I am dealing with the following problem - I was able to use NLog with Windsor Castle after many tries, but it only works if I log a message string to a file. Now I want to save the custom log information to the database but I really don't know how to do it.

My nlog.config:

```
<targets>
  <target name="file" xsi:type="File" fileName="C:\temp\example.log" layout="${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${message}|${exception}" />
  <target name="database" xsi:type="Database"    
   connectionString = "connectionString"
   commandText="INSERT INTO [dbo].[EventLog]
   (
    [CreateDate],
    [UserProfileId],
    [IsError],
    [Type],
    [Username],
    [Message],
    [Description],
    [StackTrace],
    [AddressIP]
    ) VALUES (
    @CreateDate,
    @UserProfileId,
    @IsError,
    @Type,
    @Username,
    @Message,
    @Description,
    @StackTrace,
    @AddressIP
   )">
   <parameter name="@CreateDate" layout="${event-properties:item=CreateDate}" />
   <parameter name="@UserProfileId" layout="${event-properties:item=UserProfileId}" />
   <parameter name="@IsError" layout="${event-properties:item=IsError}" />
   <parameter name="@Type" layout="${event-properties:item=Type}" />
   <parameter name="@Username" layout="${event-properties:item=Username}" />
   <parameter name="@Message" layout="${event-properties:item=Message}" />
   <parameter name="@Description" layout="${event-properties:item=Description}" />
   <parameter name="@StackTrace" layout="${event-properties:item=StackTrace}" />
   <parameter name="@AddressIP" layout="${event-properties:item=AddressIP}" />
  </target>
</targets>
<rules>
  <logger name="logger" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="database" />
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="file" />
</rules>
```

With this config (with commented database part) I'm able to write logs to "example.log".

```
 _logger.Info("test-info");
```

I tried something like this:

```
_logger.InfoFormat("\"CreateDate\": {0}, \"Message\": {1}, \"IsError\": {2}, \"Type\": {3}, \"Id\": {4}",
            new object[] {
                DateTime.Now,
                "abcd",
                true,
                1,
                Guid.NewGuid()
            });
```

But exception says that it is impossible to parse Id to unique identifier. I tried to use CASE-END in nlog.config, and I figured out that Id is not passed as parameter (probably rest of data too).

First exception:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.
```

After adding CASE WHEN @Id = '' THEN NULL ELSE convert(uniqueidentifier, @Id) END,

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'ERS.opt.Dev.dbo.EventLog'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

How to format log to pass data in schema shown above and save it to database?

Comment: Have you tried changing `<logger name="logger" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="database" />` to `<logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="database" />` ?

Comment: Have you checked the output from the NLog InternalLogger for any errors: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging

Comment: But the problem for now is that I don't know how to pass parameters to this log - there are methods only for writing message, not complex log. InternalLogger does not show any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use message templates to perform structured logging:

```
_logger.InfoFormat("\"CreateDate\": {CreateDate}, \"Message\": {Message}, \"IsError\": {IsError}, \"Type\": {Type}, \"Id\": {Id}",
            new object[] {
                DateTime.Now,
                "abcd",
                true,
                1,
                Guid.NewGuid()
            });
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging

Notice that by default then [database-target](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Database-target) `<parameter>` uses `DbType="String"`. If database-column is defined with other datatype, then make sure to explicit specify [DbType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dbtype) so it matches the column.